# Coded UI: File not found exception

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

While trying to check if an item exists in an HtmlList, i got the following exception

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Upon checking the refrences, the dll is reference but the version is 11.0.0.0
How do I solve this?

Comment: It seems like you had this project earlier developed in VS2010 and now you have moved on next version of VS, probably VS2012, that is, the reason for this error. You can search for `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension` on your Harddisk, if you can locate this. And try `devenv/resetsettings` from run menu.